# I can't trace a crash problem as VBA gives me a "Can't enter break mode" error all the time

Tags: excel, vba, crash, breakpoints

I have a long macro that has 10,000 row files.  At the end I try to fileSaveName.  It crashes all the time if I just run the macro.  I can't trace what is wrong because if I step through I get "Can't enter break mode" anywhere near the save code.  Same thing happens if I "run to cursor".  And then when I click "Continue" the macro runs to the end just fine.

When I put in a "Debug.Assert" break, the macro runs fine after clicking "Continue".

'Get active workbook folder, if saved

```
strPath = wbA.Path
If strPath = "" Then
  strPath = Application.DefaultFilePath
End If
strPath = strPath & "\"
```

'Create default name for saving file

```
strFile = QuoteNo & " - OEM List"
strPathFile = strPath & strFile
```

'Save now with Message Box

```
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=strFile, FileFilter:="Excel workbook (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", Title:="Save with this file name or Create a new name")

If fileSaveName <> False Then
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveName
End If
```

Just step through the file reformatting and filtering and save the file without breaking.

Comment: What is the value of `QuoteNo`?

Comment: Are you sure the code reaches the line `fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilenam.....`?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code (F8)? if it is really long, you can add a breakpoints too

Comment: Are you saying your VBA has 10,000 lines of code?  If so, that's really bad, not least from the point of view of understanding/ maintenance.   The usual approach would be to break it down into Subs and Functions that deal with certain smaller aspects (ideally reusable).

Comment: Value of "QuoteNo" is "Q-12345".

Comment: I have been working on this and it appears now that the crash occurs as I try to "Move" a large worksheet:  Between  "Sheets.Select" and "Sheets.Move"

Comment: I have tried stepping through and the code works most of the time when I step through the entire macro.

Comment: VBA is not 10,000 lines.  The data file that the code works with is 10,000 lines.